# Evaluate the integral (sinx-x)/x^3 based on residue

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The original quesion is
$$\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sin x}{x^3}-\frac1{x^2}\right)\,dx$$
Can I divide them into two parts? Then using residue theorem?

Comment: Are you open to solutions that don't use the residue theorem?

Comment: Please show it. Thank you.

Comment: OK, see my answer.

Comment: Both terms have a pole of order 2 at $0$, and so, their respective integrals over $(0,\infty)$ will diverge. You really need to make use of the fact that those singularities cancel out.

Comment: Let
$$f(z) = \frac {e^{i z} - e^{-i z}} {2 i z^3} - \frac 1 {z^2}, \quad
g(z) = \frac {e^{i z}} {2 i z^3},$$
then
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z) dz =
\int_{-\infty - i0}^{\infty - i0} f(z) dz =
\int_{-\infty - i0}^{\infty - i0} g(z) dz.$$
Or, in a slightly more roundabout way,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z) dz =
\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_R} f(z) dz =
\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_R} g(z) dz =
\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{|z| = R} g(z) dz,$$
where $C_R = \{ z: |z| = R \land \pi \leq \arg z \leq 2 \pi \}$, traversed in the ccw direction.

Answer (score 3):

By a [Schwinger parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization), this integral is$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{4i}\int_0^\infty dx\int_0^\infty dy(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}-2ix)y^2e^{-xy}&=\frac{1}{4i}\int_0^\infty dy\left(\frac{1}{y-i}-\frac{1}{y+i}-\frac{2i}{y^2}\right)y^2\\&=-\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{y^2+1}\\&=-\frac{\pi}{4}.\end{align}$$[WA agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28sin+x-x%29%2Fx%5E3+from+0+to+infinity&dataset=).

Answer (score 0):

If you like special functions
$$I=\int\left(\frac{\sin x}{x^3}-\frac1{x^2}\right)\,dx=-\frac{\text{Si}(x)}{2}-\frac{\sin (x)}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos (x)}{2 x}$$
$$J(p)=\int_0^p\left(\frac{\sin x}{x^3}-\frac1{x^2}\right)\,dx=-\frac{\text{Si}(p)}{2}-\frac{\sin (p)}{2 p^2}+\frac{1}{p}-\frac{\cos (p)}{2 p}$$ nad the limit of $\text{Si}(p)$ is $\frac \pi 2$.

Comment: How did you spot that antiderivative?